# Move array objects within itself according to a certain object's property

Tags: javascript, reorderlist

Suppose we have an array of objects and we want it to move some objects with a certain property to the beginning of the array, For more clarity I will give an example:

```
let arr = [
  {id:5 , tag: "X" , name:"mohsen"},
  {id:1 , tag: "A" , name:"hasan"},
  {id:3 , tag: "P" , name:"ali"},
  {id:8 , tag: "D" , name:"mehran"},
  {id:4 , tag: "C" , name:"nima"},
  {id:12 , tag: "A" , name:"keivan"},
  {id:6 , tag: "P" , name:"pedram"},
  {id:17 , tag: "X" , name:"masoud"},
  {id:20 , tag: "D" , name:"hadi"},
];
```

at this moment if we want to move objects with `tag:"P"` to beginning of array like below:

```
[
  {id: 3 ,name: "ali",tag: "P"}, 
  {id: 6,name: "pedram",tag: "P"},
  {id: 5,name: "mohsen",tag: "X"},
  {id: 1,name: "hasan",tag: "A"},
  {id: 8,name: "mehran",tag: "D"}, 
  {id: 4,name: "nima",tag: "C"}, 
  {id: 12,name: "keivan",tag: "A"},
  {id: 17,name: "masoud",tag: "X"},
  {id: 20,name: "hadi",tag: "D"}
]
```

What should we do?

Answer (score 0):

for more description, at the first we map on array then for every item of array we check that `item[propName] === propValue` condition if it is true then we cut this item from its place with `const b = arr.splice(index , 1);` and put it at beginning of array with `arr.splice(place,0,...b);` , the `place` variable track new index of beginning of array.

```js
let arr = [
  {id:5 , tag: "X" , name:"mohsen"},
  {id:1 , tag: "A" , name:"hasan"},
  {id:3 , tag: "P" , name:"ali"},
  {id:8 , tag: "D" , name:"mehran"},
  {id:4 , tag: "C" , name:"nima"},
  {id:12 , tag: "A" , name:"keivan"},
  {id:6 , tag: "P" , name:"pedram"},
  {id:17 , tag: "X" , name:"masoud"},
  {id:20 , tag: "D" , name:"hadi"},
];



function reorderListByProp(propName , propValue) {
  const rem = [];
  let place = 0;
  arr.map((item , index) => {
    if(item[propName] === propValue) {
      const b = arr.splice(index , 1);
      arr.splice(place,0,...b);
      place++;
    }
  });

  return arr;
}

console.log(reorderListByProp('tag' , 'P'));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, and tell us how it solves your issue.

Comment: @ArnavThorat thanks Arvan for your feedback, I added description about my solution on my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This will help others understand how your solution fixes the problem. _P.S. My name is Arnav, not Arvan._

Comment: @ArnavThorat I'm sorry Arnav, You are right.

Comment: Is there any restriction that prevents using `.sort()`? Because, `arr.sort((a, b) => a[propName] === propValue ? -1 : 1)` will mutate `arr` into the required order. For a solution that does not mutate `arr`, this should work: `structuredClone(arr).sort((a, b) => a[col] === val ? -1 : 1)`.

Comment: @ArnavThorat I Followed you on Github.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I don't usually post much code in my public repositories.

Comment: @jsN00b yes it is correct too but I want to keep order of object of same `propertyName` from top to bottom of list after reordering, for example if before reordering we have XX before YY (assume XX and YY have the object with the same propertyName) I want keep order after reordering like previous figure that mean XX puts before YY

Comment: By `propertyName` you mean the prop `name` (like `'ali'`, `'hasan'`, etc)? If so, that's also achieved in much simpler method within `.sort()`. Plus, was that criteria mentioned in the question, or may be in the description added to this answer - and I've missed it?

Comment: @jsN00b the `propertyName` is like `id`,`name`,`tag` that are keys of object